# How to: Silverlight 4 business appliacation Form athentication with stand alone database

Tags: silverlight, authentication, silverlight-4.0

I am working on a silverlight 4 business application.  for the form based authentication I created a user database  with all the user, role and profile tables on SQL Express.

In my VS2010 ASP.NET configuration I can see and manage my users and roles by adding, removing or modifying them.  So, I assume my app.config connectionstrings settings are correct because I can see the changes in my database if i add a new user from APS.Net config.

If I run the application compiled locally on the server, it sees the users because it doesn't allow me to create and register a new user iwth the same name.  but I cannot login or register another user with error:"Load operation failed for query 'Login'.  A profile property does not exist for FriendlyName...'

The same application, if i ran it from a client PC on my login, generates a "Load operation failed for query "GetUser'.  The remote server returned an error: NotFound".

What is wrong?  What settings I am missing?

Thanks a lot,
Val

Answer (score 1):

You must add your FriendlyName property to profile in your Web.config

< system.web>< profile>
            < properties>
                < add name="FriendlyName "/>
            < /properties>
        < /profile> < /system.web>

Sample of custom authentication 
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/26/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-authentication-and-personalization.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a age old post, this is just for those who might be currently faced with this issue.

That error usually presents it self when the application is published with the "Precompiled during publishing" option is checked. Uncheck this option in the "File Publish Options" of the Settings area before publishing.

That should help